# If a ServerSocket is garbage-collected, what happens to its associated port binding?

Tags: java, networking, serversocket

I want to create an application that can detect other instances of itself and prevent them from running.  To accomplish this, I'm thinking of opening up a new `ServerSocket` on some application-specific port, and then relying on the exception that should be thrown if I try to bind to the same port more than once to "detect" and kill duplicate application instances.  I know I could do something like write a file into the present-working-directory and "detect" it to accomplish the same sort of behavior, but I really don't want to do this (what happens if the app dies and can't remove the file?), so that's why I've chosen the `ServerSocket` route.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new ServerSocket(1234);

        new Thread(){
            //This is a non-daemon thread. Assume its run() method never returns.
        }.start();
    }
}
```

**Question**

Short of creating the `ServerSocket`, my application never really needs to use it again, because its mere existence allows me to detect when another instance of my app attempts to start up.  Thus, saving a reference to said `ServerSocket` will result in a compile warning (unused reference).  I'm a neat-freak, so I'd rather not save a reference if I can avoid it.  My question is, will this `ServerSocket` instance get garbage collected before all non-daemon threads exit (assuming the app doesn't fail or exit some other way), and if so, will its associated port become unbound as a result?

Comment: This sounds like a horrible idea. If you really want to keep a single instance of your class, I'd look into using D-bus http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus . I'm sure windows has something similar.

Comment: @Falmarri, you are incorrect.  The idea is not a singleton class, it's a singleton program.  I want to make sure that that particular main() method is never executed more than once on a ***per-machine*** basis, not per-JVM.

Comment: @Falmarri This is standard technique. Two lines of code as opposed to an external product? No-brainer.

Comment: @BenLawry OTOH I don't think a one-line static variable declaration is going to kill you.

Comment: @EJP you're right, it's not.  Guess I'm just wishing the behavior of ServerSocket and garbage collection was a little better-defined. Then again, I think anyone who has ever written Java code wishes Java garbage collection was a little better-defined ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused: you're a "neat freak" but would rather leave socket closing to the whims of the garbage collector than have a close procedure under the control of the application in the case of a normal exit? (I assume this to be the case, because to put such a mechanism in place you would need to hold a reference, thus eliminating your perceived problem.)

For what it's worth, I don't think that there'll actually be a problem in practice if you don't hold on to the reference:

- internally, it is likely that a reference will be held while the socket is bound
- it is likely that the ServerSocket's close() method will be called on garbage collection. It is called in the finalize() method of AbstractPlainSocketImpl, so in principle will be called, with the proviso that there is no guarantee that any finalize method will actually get called.
- if the application terminates abnormally, there is no *guarantee* that the socket will be unbound *immediately*, though on recent O/Ses it is likely to be (best to test this).

However, I would really recommend coding a "clean" shutdown mechanism for the case where your app is shut down cleanly, and for that you will need to hold on to a reference to the socket. So I think you're really inventing a problem for yourself that need not exist if you just use sensible programming practice instead.

Comment: Not sure how you read the question that way, so let me clarify - I'd rather leave this particular socket closing to the exiting of the JVM and the underlying O/S, NOT the garbage collector, I am just curious as to what the garbage collector would actually do if I wrote my program this way.  To begin your answer with an insult and assume that I'm not using "sensible programming practice instead" begs the question,  and isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: "There is no guarantee that the socket will be unbound immediately, though on recent O/Ses it is likely to be (best to test this)". The operating system provides exactly this guarantee in all cases I have used over 25 years excluding Netware.

Comment: @EJP Congratulations that the OS's you've used give this guarantee and that it has always worked without fail for you. I've used ones where one of these conditions hasn't been true... :-) [Including at least one version of an operating system called "Windows".]

Comment: @NeilCoffey You missed the part about Netware: it didn't release certain resources, that's why I mentioned it. All versions of Windows I have used since 3.0 were supposed to release all process resources on process exit. If they didn't, it was a bug. Not something that needs to be guaranteed *by Java.*

Comment: More to the point - it appears that `ServerSocket` directly extends `Object`, but doesn't override `finalize()`.  It would seem that `ServerSocket` instances that aren't closed explicitly before garbage collection don't actually give up their native resources prior to their parent JVM exiting.

Comment: @BenLawry But it is also documented to rely on a `SocketFactory` that creates `SocketImpls` that do-or can- have finalizers without you knowing about it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let me try to redeem myself from my previous wrong understanding. The file lock and socket techniques that you mention are widely used but there is another one - having an observer that will keep the current instance of yor program (through methods register and deregister).

If a new instance tries to register while there is another one running, the registration process will fail and your application could close gracefully.

Your application could then implement an interface Observable that would contain one method beObserved in order for your observer to know that your application is still alive. Therefore, if your application crashes, the periodic check would fail and it would deregister the crashed application automatically.